# How to remove sub string

Tags: c#, string, substring, substr

I have a string -> 1234,2345,12341,6442

Need to remove 12341 in above string through C# code and my string should be 1234,2345,6442 in C#

Comment: look up string replace.

Comment: What is the rule here? Why should `12341` be deleted? Please share the code that is not working for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using simple string replace:

```
namespace ReplaceExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1234,2345,12341,6442".Replace("12341,", string.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```

Considering that the number to replace may be the last element the comma should not included to replace pattern, so using Regex may be a more elegant solution:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;    

namespace ReplaceExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("1234,2345,12341,6442", @"12341[,]*", string.Empty));
        }
    }
}
```